# Recording notes with the computer keyboard in Ableton Live

Tags: software, daw, ableton-live

I have enabled the Computer keyboard button, the Arm Session Recording, and playing/recording at the same time, plus the Midi Editor Preview. If I press the ASD buttons, I can hear notes (as long as it's not recording) but it is neither playing those notes nor writing them to the track. How do I get it to do this?

[image: Ableton Live 10 screenshot]

Comment: Have you read the manual on "Recording Into Session Slots"? https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/recording-new-clips/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to **not** have the session record armed or active. You want to just record into a clip. To record into a clip, all you have to do is record arm the track and then click the record button (circle) in one of the clip spaces on the track. There are a lot of relevant settings, like fixed length recording, that you might have to run down, but that’s the basics of it.

One thing I note in the image is that the selected clip is in play mode and not record mode. You can tell because of the green triangle on the left side of the clip box. If it were recording into the clip, that would be a red circle. One way that might happen while the track is record armed is if you clicked the clip button once to begin recording and then clicked it again, which by default stops recording and starts playing the clip. Another way that might happen is if fixed length recording is on, then you click record and then don’t play until after the fixed length is already exceeded then the clip can enter playback mode automatically. If you click the open circle to the right of the transport buttons that should put the clip in overdub mode and you should be able to play midi events into it.